# ANOVA gives small effect yet significant p

Tags: r, anova

I have a mixed design anova with 3 factors: drug (placebo vs. treatment), timing (pre, vs post-treatment), age group (young vs. elderly). The first two factors are within-subject and the third factor is between subject. I constructed the data frame and all the means look correct. There are total of 20 participants (10 young, 10 old). However the anova results are strange.

snippet of data

```
   part timing drug age freq_disc
1     1    pre  trt   Y  5.231433
2     2    pre  trt   Y  1.817267
3     3    pre  trt   Y  2.501767
4     4    pre  trt   Y  2.044167
5     5    pre  trt   Y  1.914400
6     6    pre  trt   Y  2.409567
7     7    pre  trt   Y  2.100533
8     8    pre  trt   Y  3.671033
9     9    pre  trt   Y  2.753967
10   10    pre  trt   Y  1.226233 

summary(anova_data)
      part     timing    drug    age      freq_disc      
 1      : 4   post:40   trt:40   O:40   Min.   : 0.9082  
 2      : 4   pre :40   plc:40   Y:40   1st Qu.: 1.7650  
 3      : 4                             Median : 2.4022  
 4      : 4                             Mean   : 3.8784  
 5      : 4                             3rd Qu.: 4.0412  
 6      : 4                             Max.   :24.6799  
 (Other):56
```

anova command:

```
ez_an <- ezANOVA( data=anova_data, dv=freq_disc, wid=part, within=.(timing,drug), between=age ) 

$ANOVA
           Effect DFn DFd         F          p p<.05          ges
2             age   1  18 3.7628945 0.06823574       1.689433e-01
3          timing   1  18 3.3200863 0.08509702       2.556813e-03
5            drug   1  18 6.9669754 0.01665407     * 3.858303e-03
4      age:timing   1  18 0.1206849 0.73232183       9.316952e-05
6        age:drug   1  18 1.4761135 0.24008106       8.199634e-04
7     timing:drug   1  18 8.6809914 0.00863464     * 1.762140e-03
8 age:timing:drug   1  18 0.1939504 0.66489196       3.943761e-05
```

My question is: is it possible to have such significant effects of drug with those small effect sizes (ges column) given that the participants are only 20 total?

Comment: Power depends on $\Delta/\sigma,$ where $\Delta$ is size of difference to detect and σ is population standard deviation. So if σ (estimated by SD of appropriate residuals) is very small, then you can have small P-values for small actual differences. Will try to illustrate in Answer using t test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two different scenarios that are alike, except that the smaller
population standard deviation $\sigma$ in the second scenario gives high power for
detecting the distance $\Delta = 1$ between two population means.

**Scenario 1:**  Normal population 1 has $\mu_1 = 100,$ normal population 2 has
$\mu_2 = 101,$ both populations have $\sigma = 5.$ Consider samples of size $n_1=n_2=10.$
In these circumstances a Welch two-sample t test rejects at the 5% level only about 7%
of the time. So it will be rare to find a significant difference when the real difference is 1.

```
set.seed(715)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10,100,5),rnorm(10,101,5))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.06871
```

A typical two-sample dataset in this scenario can be summarized as follows. It is one of the many such datasets in which no significant difference is found.

```
set.seed(715)
x1 = rnorm(10, 100, 5)
summary(x1);  sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  91.74   99.73   99.96   99.92  101.39  106.41 
[1] 3.665256  ## SD for Sample 1
x2 = rnorm(10, 101, 5)
summary(x2);  sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  90.97  100.43  101.77  102.09  106.09  110.95 
[1] 5.801608  ## SD for Sample 2

boxplot(x1,x2, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

```
t.test(x1, x2)

         Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -0.99765, df = 15.197, p-value = 0.3341
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.785208  2.455214
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 99.92492 102.08991
```

**Scenario 2:**  Normal population 1 has $\mu_1 = 100,$ normal population 2 has
$\mu_2 = 101,$ both populations have the smaller standard deviation $\sigma = 0.5.$ Again, consider samples of size $n_1=n_2=10.$
In these circumstances a Welch two-sample t test rejects at the 5% level over 98%
of the time. So one will almost always find a significant difference when the real difference is 1.

```
set.seed(716)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10,100,.5),rnorm(10,101,.5))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.98746
```

A typical two-sample dataset in this scenario can be summarized as follows. It is one of the many such datasets in which a significant difference is found.

```
y1 = rnorm(10, 100, .5)    
summary(y1);  sd(y1)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   99.41  100.07  100.25  100.22  100.40  100.89 
[1]  0.4248364
y2 = rnorm(10, 101, .5)
summary(y2);  sd(y2)    
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  100.2   100.8   101.0   101.0   101.3   101.6 
[1] 0.4327343
```

This boxplot uses about the same horizontal scale as the previous one.

```
boxplot(y1,y2, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=20, ylim=c(91,111))
```

[image]

```
t.test(y1, y2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y1 and y2
t = -3.9775, df = 17.994, p-value = 0.0008835
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.1656442 -0.3598506
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 100.2202  100.9830
```

Comment: thanks for the nice explanation